# Multiple input validation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 inputs that I need to check if any are empty and then run an ajax call.

Could someone assist write the IF statement

```
$('input[name=newsave]').click(function(){
            var neworgy = $('input[name=neworg]').val();
            var newurly = $('input[name=newurl]').val();
            var newtrackingy = $('input[name=newtracking]').val();
            var dataString = 'email=<?php echo $userid;?>&neworg='+ neworgy +'&newurl='+ newurly +'&newtracking='+ newtrackingy;
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "new-token.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    location.reload();
                    }
              });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isValid = !$('input[name=neworg], input[name=newurl], input[name=newtracking]')
    .filter(function() {
        return !this.value;
    }).length;​

if (isValid){
    // Do what you want
}
```

For the query string you can use the jQuery [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.